# How to get access to a public network Github repo via enterprise account

Tags: github, github-enterprise

I am a student who works with github account with edu suffix. There are some repository I would like to work with my current account assigned by school. All I know is that my school account is kind of github enterprise account.Basically, I would like to always works in only one account rather than switch beteen two accounts. Is the demand weird? Cause I didn't see any similar demand before.

So what I want to know is it possible. Also I feel like misunderstanding some fundamental principle of github which I couldn't tell.

Wish some guys could point it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem I can read out of your question is that you want to access public repositories on GitHub. The answer to this question is you can handle this with your student account. With the Enterprise license you should even have more features like public repositories etc.

For your second part some information about GitHub which might help you to understand the first answer.

You can always access public repositories, clone them on your machine and modify them and use all the features of git locally. The only thing that is not possible is pushing to the public repository if you don't have write access to this repository.

If you want to push some modifications to this repository you can do a fork of this. Then you will have this fork under your name and you also have write access. Now you are able to push your changes to this repository.

If you want to have your modifications also in the original repository you can do a pull request with your pushed commits of your own repository. The owner of the original repository now can decide to accept the pull request. Accepting the request will merge your changes in the original repository.

I hope this was the information you were looking for.

Comment: Really appreciate for answer the question. It sounds reasonable that I can do things you describe, but things is I can't even search public repos or my normal account via my school account.

Comment: So if you are using the github search from your school account you can't find your other account? But if you directly go to the url of you account while you are logged in to your school account? I guess I still didn't got your problem.